# How i control if an userbot is limited?

Tags: telethon

how i can control if an userbot is in FloodWait or PeerFlood(is limited) without do an invite/chat request?
I send a message to SpamBot but it informs me only if the userbot is limited, no if is in FloodWait.
Thanks and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: The answer you received was not correct. I gave a better answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62566281/1508101).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> How can I check if **my** userbot is restricted?

You can check only if your self is restricted, that means you can't check if a different user is restricted.

```
import asyncio
from telethon import TelegramClient

name = 'test'
api_id   = '1043101'
api_hash = '5ade788056adad54e71aa558e38337bc'
client = TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash)
client.start(phone=+xxxxxxxxxx)

async def main():
    if (await client_get_me()).restricted):
        print('I'm restricted')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: This is incorrect, see the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62566281/1508101).

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [Telethon docs](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/concepts/errors.html#common-errors) for how to handle the various RPC errors gracefully.

Example for FloodWait From the docs:

```py
from telethon import errors

try:
    messages = await client.get_messages(chat)
    print(messages[0].text)
except errors.FloodWaitError as e:
    print('Have to sleep', e.seconds, 'seconds')
    time.sleep(e.seconds)
```